# Can't Display the other table

Tags: php, sql

I'm a little bit new to the SQL and PHP how do I display the output with three different tables? I can only display it in one table but I don't know how to group them up in 3 different tables? Here's the output:

[image]

```
<?php

include "Connection.php";

$sql = "SELECT artist.artistName, artistcd.artistID, artistcd.cdID, artistcd.cdTitle, artistcd.cdGenre, artistcd.cdPrice FROM artist, artistcd WHERE artist.artistID = artistcd.artistID ORDER BY artistcd.artistID" ;


 $query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($connect));;


?>
<table width="70%" cellpadding="5" cellspace="5">

<tr>
    <th>Genre</th>
    <th>CD Identification</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    </tr>

<?php 

    $name = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    echo $name["artistID"] . $name["artistName"];

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['cdGenre']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['cdID']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['cdTitle']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['cdPrice']. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
}
?>

<table width="70%" cellpadding="5" cellspace="5">

</table>
```

Comment: take an empty array and then apply while once and assign all the values to that array and then use that array variable into three different table

Comment: What's the difference between the 3 tables? Is there a grouping you need to do? You will probably need to make 3 separate queries. Or define a logic for splitting your results on 3 inside the for loop.

Comment: @LeonelAtencio yes the 3 tables shows 3 different Artist name and have 3 different songs

Comment: Ok, then i would suggest you do 3 different queries!. Wait for my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the simplest thing would be for you to repeat that code block 3 times. Each time, with a different Artist ID passed to the Query:

```
<?php
include "Connection.php";
$sql = "SELECT artist.artistName, artistcd.artistID, artistcd.cdID, artistcd.cdTitle, artistcd.cdGenre, artistcd.cdPrice 
        FROM artist, artistcd 
        WHERE artist.artistID = "$ArtistID1";

$query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($connect));;
$name = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    echo "<p>" . $name["artistID"] . $name["artistName"] . "</p>";
?>

<table width="70%" cellpadding="5" cellspace="5">
<tr>
    <th>Genre</th>
    <th>CD Identification</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    </tr>

    <?php 
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['cdGenre']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['cdID']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['cdTitle']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['cdPrice']. "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
    }
    ?>

<table width="70%" cellpadding="5" cellspace="5">
</table>


<?php
$sql = "SELECT artist.artistName, artistcd.artistID, artistcd.cdID, artistcd.cdTitle, artistcd.cdGenre, artistcd.cdPrice 
        FROM artist, artistcd 
        WHERE artist.artistID = "$ArtistID2";

$query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($connect));;
$name = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    echo "<p>" . $name["artistID"] . $name["artistName"] . "</p>";
?>

<table width="70%" cellpadding="5" cellspace="5">
<tr>
    <th>Genre</th>
    <th>CD Identification</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    </tr>

    <?php 
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['cdGenre']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['cdID']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['cdTitle']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['cdPrice']. "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
    }
    ?>

<table width="70%" cellpadding="5" cellspace="5">
</table>


<?php
$sql = "SELECT artist.artistName, artistcd.artistID, artistcd.cdID, artistcd.cdTitle, artistcd.cdGenre, artistcd.cdPrice 
        FROM artist, artistcd 
        WHERE artist.artistID = "$ArtistID3";

$query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($connect));;
$name = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    echo "<p>" . $name["artistID"] . $name["artistName"] . "</p>";
?>

<table width="70%" cellpadding="5" cellspace="5">
<tr>
    <th>Genre</th>
    <th>CD Identification</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    </tr>

    <?php 
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['cdGenre']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['cdID']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['cdTitle']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['cdPrice']. "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
    }
    ?>

<table width="70%" cellpadding="5" cellspace="5">
</table>
```

Another way would be to query once for all the artists, and build the 3 tables by filtering the artists right from your associative array. But as you say you are just starting, i think this solution will do it.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$ArtistID1' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Exer42\New folder\display_music.php on line 15

Comment: You need to replace $ArtistID1, $ArtistID2 and $ArtistID3 with the actual Artist ID's!...

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, if the id of the person is on all 3 tables.

You can use JOIN

[See This For More Info](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

```
SELECT mytable1.id, mytable2.order, mytable3.price FROM mytable1 WHERE mytable1.id=7 JOIN mytable2 ON mytable1.id=mytable2.id JOIN mytable3 ON mytable1.id= mytable3.id
```